# Add RBAC role on a Azure blob storage container with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm deploying an azure datalake gen 2 storage account with bicep.
I want to assign roles (groups) on a containers with bicep (see code below). But I keep getting an error. Can someone help me ?

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup' 

param location string =resourceGroup().location
param storageAccountName string

resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    isHnsEnabled: true
  }
}

resource bs 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: stg
}


resource container 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'help'
  parent: bs
}

resource rbac  'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(container.id,'xxx')
  scope: container
  properties: {
    principalId: 'xxx'
    principalType: 'Group'
    roleDefinitionId: '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1'
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequestFormat\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The request was incorrectly formatted.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments?tabs=bicep) you should add a condition but this also doesn't work.

```
condition: '@Resource[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers:ContainerName] StringEqualsIgnoreCase \'help\''
```

Comment: can you try with `roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `roleDefinitionId` property is the resource identifier of the role. It is also a subscription level resource so you would define it in the bicep file like that:

```bicep
roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')
```

Comment: I'm hoping this will also be the answer to my latest question - will update soon!