# Azure role assignment - BadRequestFormat

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'd like to create a storage account and add a role assignment to the service principal of an azure devops pipeline service connection - so that it's able to read a file in blob storage.

I already have a bicep module in a registry that gets used for creating storage accounts - this module is well used so that's not the problem.

My bicep is:

```
var storageAccountName = 'st${baseResourceNameAlpha}'
module storageAccount 'br:urlhere.azurecr.io/bicep/modules/storageaccount:v22.10.03.02' = {
  name: 'storageAccountDeployment'
  params: {
    name: storageAccountName
  }
}

resource storageAc 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}
//corrected blobReaderRole thanks to comment from Thomas
//    var blobReaderRole = '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1'
var blobReaderRole =  subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')
var principalId = 'principal id of my dev ops svc conn'

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  scope: storageAc
  name: guid(storageAc.id, principalId, blobReaderRole)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: blobReaderRole
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
BadRequestFormat The request was incorrectly formatted
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Also, currently I get the principal id of the svc connection from the Enterprise Application page of the Azure portal. Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName doesn't seem to work for service principals. Is there another way?

Comment: The `roleDefinitionId` should be a resourceId. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71762537/4167200

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This then gives: PrincipalTypeNotSupported. Principals of type Application cannot validly be used in role assignments. I've 'ServicePrincipal' and 'User' as values for the 'principalType' property?

Comment: you need the objectid of the related service principal not the object id of the app registration

Comment: I think the `Get-AzADUser`~will give you the connected app not service principal

Comment: Thanks again Thomas, I was using the object id of the app registration rather than its enterprise application. I've made it work by hard-coding the value taken from the Azure portal. Do you know if it's possible to lookup this value from the name of the enterprise app using bicep? Also, do you want to add your roleDefinitionId as an answer an I'll make as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `roleDefinitionId` property needs to be the `resourceId` of the role definition:

```
roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')
```

Also the `principalId` property needs to be the objectId of the service principal not the objectId of the application.
You can't really get it using pure bicep/arm. There is an open issue regarding that:

- [Scope function: Azure Client ID](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4959)

Before deploying your bicep template, you could always look it up using Az CLI or Az Powershell and pass it as a parameter of your template:

```
$appId = (az account show | ConvertFrom-Json).user.name
$principalId = (az ad sp show --id $appId | ConvertFrom-Json).id
```